# Why is drop location required?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to create a new build definition for TFS 2010. I clearly mark that I do not need to copy files to output folder. Why do I still get this error?

> TF270006: The drop location for this build was empty. The build
>   definition 'CI Project' (or the build request) must specify a valid
>   UNC path as the drop location for the build. Update the build
>   definition and try again

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set `Copy Outputs to Drop Folder` = False by going to Edit Build Definition then Click Process and then click Expand and then in Advanced

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716(v=vs.100).aspx)

> This build copies output files to a drop folder check box should
>   remain selected. Your builds will fail if you clear this check box and
>   use a build template that produces output.

Comment: This works. But I still want to know why there are 2 separate options to turn the same feature off.

Comment: @user3918598:- I didnt get that! P.S. You may also accept the answer if that helped you so that it may help others in future! :)

Comment: My question is "Why"? You helped me with "How" though.

Comment: @user3918598:- The simple answer to this is that it is designed that way. You need to have a dropped location! :)

Comment: @user3918598 Because you're using VS 2012 (and the TFS 2012 client) against TFS 2010.  This option didn't exist in TFS 2010.

Answer (score -1):

See by adding /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 in MSBuild arguments.